# Reading MongoDB documents into Haskell data types

Tags: json, mongodb, haskell, serialization

My ultimate goal is to return a JSON response from a scotty endpoint that runs a MongoDB query. So far I've got the query written down, but it returns a Document and I want to turn that Document into a custom type that I've defined.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
data User = User { username :: String } deriving (Show, Read)

getUsers :: Pipe -> IO [Document]
getUsers pipe = access pipe master "mydb" (find (select [] "users") >>= rest)

server :: Pipe -> ScottyM()
server pipe =
    get "/" $ do
        res <- liftIO $ getUsers pipe
        -- json $ T.pack $ show res
```

The last line is where I get the query result and I'm wondering how can I easily turn the Document data into the User type I have declared at the top. The commented out line is my attempt at some kind of serialization but unfortunately the result is not valid JSON.

Comment: Where is the `Document` type coming from?

Comment: `Document` is what a `Database.MongoDB.Query` returns and it's definition can be found here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.3.2.3/docs/Data-Bson.html#t:Document